# Conditional formatting to check if column meets a specific format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I want my column in excel to only allow values that have this format: 628-XXXX-A (where XXXX can be a number between 0001 and 00125) and otherwise I want the cell to color red.

Does anyone know how to write this in a formula?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You will need only `Data Validation` to stop this, `Conditional Formatting` is not required, because using a condition in `Data Validation` you can stop entering the other types ! Or if you have a data already and what to highlight the offending ones, then you need `Conditional Formatting`

Comment: You may use this formula to `CF` or use in `DV` --> `=AND(ISNUMBER(TEXTBEFORE(A1,"-")/1),LEFT(TEXTAFTER(A1,"-"),4)/1>=1,LEFT(TEXTAFTER(A1,"-"),4)/1<=125)` however this doesnt takes into consideration about the last text character if that is a condition then please specify. Think this is shorter: `=AND(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,1,3)), --MID(A1,5,4) >= 1, --MID(A1,5,4) <= 125)`

Answer (score 0):

As commented above you may try using one of the following formulas, in either **`Conditional Formatting`** or in **`Data Validation`**

In **`Conditional Formatting`** this will highlight those offending ones to `Red` if applied the rules and if using in **`Data Validation`** one could use the **`Custom Validation Option`** to stop entering those values which dont match the criteria.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(-LEFT(A1,3)), --MID(A1,5,4) >= 1, --MID(A1,5,4) <= 125)
```

---

Or,

• Formula can also be used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=LET(α,LEFT(TEXTAFTER(B1,"-"),4)/1,AND(ISNUMBER(TEXTBEFORE(B1,"-")/1),α>=1,α<=125))
```

---

**Notes:** That the above formulas doesn't considers about the `9th` & `10th` characters, it completely works based on the first `3` numbers and the numbers after the `1st` dash and before `2nd` dash.

---

Answer (score 0):

If you insist doing this using conditional formatting, I would advise you to use an UDF (User-Defined Function) for this, something like:

```
Function isCorrectFormat(r As Range)
  Test = Split(r.Value, "-")
  bResult = True
  If Test(0) <> "628" Then
  bResult = False
  End If
  If (CInt(Test(1)) < 1) Or (CInt(Test(1)) > 125) Then
    bResult = False
  End If
  If Test(2) <> "A" Then
    bResult = False
  End If
  isCorrectFormat = bResult
End Function
```

Building this into an Excel sheet yields following result:

[image: Excel screenshot]

For your information: column "B" contains the formula `=IsCorrectFormat(Ax)`, which shows you what the result will look like and can be used for debugging purposes.